# How to convert XML into XLSX and then back into XML while ensuring that the XML structure remains the same?

Tags: xml, excel

**Question**: **How to convert XML into XLSX and then back into XML while ensuring that the XML structure remains the same?**

**Question in detail**: I am trying to do the following.

1. Convert XML into excel format (xlsx) and then
2. Add multiple new records in excel (copy, paste and modify) and then
3. export the data back into XML.

I am successful in steps 1 and 2. However, I am not able to export from xlsx.  Initially I got an '*XML mapping not found*' error. 
After that I added XML map (I created a xsd document and then mapped the fields in excel to the xml mapping document). 
However, I am still not able to export. 
I get error which says  *'XML map is not exportable as it contains the following a. List of lists b. Denormalized data and c. A mapped elements relationship with other elements cannot be preserved*.'

Note #1: 
I have tried the following and they don't work as I expect them to.

a. Save XLSX as 2003 xml format - This creates XML with completely different xml structure.

b. Convert XLSX into XML online - Again xml structure is different.

Note #2: 
I don't have the liberty to change my xml structure/ xml tag names.

I have posted sample XML below

```
<tXML>
<Item>
<ItemName>AC0003-101-MISC</ItemName>
<BusinessUnit>1</BusinessUnit>
<ReferenceField4>CONVERSION</ReferenceField4>
<ItemPackageList>
<ItemPackage>
<PkgUOM>Packs</PkgUOM>
<Weight>0.2100</Weight>
<Quantity>6.0000</Quantity>
<WeightUOM>KG</WeightUOM>
<UnitLength>27.3000</UnitLength>
<UnitHeight>3.1000</UnitHeight>
<UnitWidth>17.7000</UnitWidth>
<DimensionUOM>CM</DimensionUOM>
<UnitVolume>1497.9510</UnitVolume>
<VolumeUOM>CCM</VolumeUOM>
<IsStandard>1</IsStandard>
</ItemPackage>
<ItemPackage>
<PkgUOM>Cases</PkgUOM>
<Weight>12.8000</Weight>
<Quantity>360.0000</Quantity>
<WeightUOM>KG</WeightUOM>
<UnitLength>38.5000</UnitLength>
<UnitHeight>13.0000</UnitHeight>
<UnitWidth>29.5000</UnitWidth>
<DimensionUOM>CM</DimensionUOM>
<UnitVolume>14764.7500</UnitVolume>
<VolumeUOM>CCM</VolumeUOM>
<IsStandard>1</IsStandard>
<ItemWmos>
<ConveyFlag>Y</ConveyFlag>
<SplInstrCode10/>
<SplInstr1>FN</SplInstr1>
</ItemWmos>
</Item>
</Message>
</tXML>
```

Comment: Show us the originating XML and the XLSX that refuses to translate.

Comment: Hi Bob, I have appended the XML to the original post now. Thanks.